# Where do I change the Login Url in ASP NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I tried to change:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="login" protection="All" timeout="30" loginUrl="~/User1/Login" defaultUrl="~/">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230). Try adding the `loginUrl` key to the `appSettings` section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/User1/Login" />
<appSettings>
```